# How to compare many booleans to pass through specific outputs? C++ for UE4

Tags: c++, boolean, compare, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I myself am not a programmer, but I have a programmer friend who is trying to help me with a certain task in Unreal Engine 4, and I was hoping to find some advice here to pass on to him.

What we are trying to make is a 'Node' in UE4 that can take in many boolean values (20+), and pass out specific values, or rather to pass through the event chain/line.

For example, I could have 6 booleans coming into the node, and I would want one of the outputs to pass through if boolean 2 and 4 were true, 1 was false, and the rest aren't looked at (essentially N/A). I made a quick image below to showcase what it would look like.

[Example Of What Node would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43SnS.jpg)

My friend says he is not sure how such a node could be accomplished in C++, so I am hoping someone here can help give us a nudge in the right direction. Otherwise, I'll be stuck messing with branch nodes, and nodes, or nodes, and the like till my ears bleed and my project looks like a bowl of spaghetti.

---

Thanks for the suggestion, but I feel that that implementation is a bit too simple for what I am needing.

Hhhmmm, maybe I can explain my thoughts to the logic of it. Essentially, have the incoming boolean values into the node be made into an array of integers(or floats, dont know the difference between them really), with True = 1, and False = 2. The number of inputs to the array node can be determined by the number of inputs into the main Node.
Then, based on the number of inputs into the main Node, you can that same number of options per each event out pin on the main Node. Each option would have 3 check boxes. Checking the first box would output a 1 for True, second box would output 2 for False, and third box would output 3 for Dont Check.
These outputs could then be made into an array themselves. And then you would just have to compare the two arrays to see if they match, and anywhere there is a 3 value in the second array, that would output an 'is matching' regardless of what it is being compared to.
I just don't know actual coding, so I need a bit of help to try and explain this line of logic to my buddy, in terms of code.

Comment: **you can that same number of options per each event out pin on the main Node** please clarify

Comment: Like, in the image, on the right hand side of the screen under Pin options, there are a bunch of check boxes under Case_1. Ideally, those same check boxes would appear under Case_0, and any additional output pins that you create. On the node in the middle of the screen, you can see the option to "Add Pin", that is what would create a Case_2, Case_3, etc. My thought is that each of those 'case' things would have its own set of check boxes, which could be turned into their own arrays, and checked against the main input array. That clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information:

```
std::vector<int> input_vector; //the index will represent sequence and value will represent state

for(int i=0; i<node_size; i++)
{
    input_vector.push_back(state); //you will push state=1 or state=2 here
}

std::vector<int> node_vector;
bool flag = true;

for(int case_no=0; case_no<cases;case_no++)
{
    //checking node_vector with input_vector
    for(int i=0; i<node_size; i++)
    {
        int choice;
        std::cin >> choice; //either 1 or 2 or 3
        node_vector.push_back(choice);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<node_size; i++)
    {
        if(node_vector[i]==3)
            continue;
        else if(node_vector[i]==input_vector[i])
            continue;
        else
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==true)
        break;
    else
        continue;
}

if(flag)
    std::cout << "Matched";
else
    std::cout << "Not Matched";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but see the edit above. :D

Comment: There are multi[le cases at the node and we will have to find matched/not matched for each of them?

Comment: Um.. I think so? Basically, I would need to have only one output ever be true at once, or it would break things in UE4. So, bascially, every time the node is 'activated', it would check through all of the output pin arrays until it finds one that matches the input array, otherwise it would have a 'none matching' output, I guess? Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I'll pass this along to my programmer friend to see if this helps him make sense of things. :D

Comment: do tell me the final result:)